# How can I know the relation between a `FormsModule` and `ngModel`?

Tags: angular, module, directive

From the angular hero editor tutorial, I have a question about `FormsModule`.

In this part, the demo is not working without importing `FormsModule`:
 https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#the-missing-formsmodule

```
The missing FormsModule
Notice that the app stopped working when you added [(ngModel)].
```

Then

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

And add it to the `imports` of `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It will be OK.

My question is I can't find any relation between `FormsModule` and `ngModel`, I just import `FormsModule` here, and `ngModel` is working in another place, like magic.

I also go to the definition of `FormsModule`, and it's quite simple:

```
export declare class FormsModule {
}
```

So without the document, there is no clue in the code that `ngModel` is coming from `FormsModule`. I though somewhere may have something like `import ngModel from FormsModule`, but there is not.

Comment: You can look at the `ngModel` API documentation https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel to see which module declares it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern Angular team uses is they have `public_api.d.ts` files here and there, which define the exports. In this case if you go up to the parent folder, you'll find that file. Then you'll see it exports all from `./src/forms.d.ts`, and if you look at that file, you'll find everything actually exported by that module.

Having said that, documentation should always be the first place you need to look at when using libraries, not type defs or source code. Usually it is all in the docs, though of course in the case of some shadier libs it might not be.